windows server 2019: Enable file share access using powershell
I am not a windows expert or powershell expert. I experimented in the last few days and still could not do it successfully and hence the question.

My setup is on virtualbox with 2 VMs.
First VM (linux01) is running linux. Samba is enabled on it and a
folder is created to be shared.
Second VM (windows01) is running Windows Server 2019. The folder shared on linux01 is to be mapped in windows01 as Z:
I am trying to create this setup using two separate Vagrantfiles,
one each for each VM. Each Vagrantfile runs bash and powershell
script respectively for this.
On windows01, the shared folder does
not get mapped if I try to run this through a Powershell script. If
I do this manually, the shared folder gets mapped as Z: drive on
windows 01.

This is what I have tried in my last attempt as Powershell Script
# Limit Blank Password Use
$PolicyPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policie
s\System"
$PolicyName = "LimitBlankPasswordUse"
$PolicyValue = 1 # Enable the policy
# Check if the policy already exists
if (!(Test-Path -Path $PolicyPath\$PolicyName)) {
    # Create the policy if it doesn't exist
    New-ItemProperty -Path $PolicyPath -Name $PolicyName -PropertyType DWord -Value $PolicyValue
} else {
    # Update the policy if it exists
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $PolicyPath -Name $PolicyName -Value $PolicyValue
}

# Verify the policy setting
$PolicyValue = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $PolicyPath -Name $PolicyName).LimitBlankPasswordUse
if ($PolicyValue -eq 1) {
    Write-Host "Policy 'Limit local account use of blank passwords to console logon only' is enabled."
} else {
    Write-Host "Policy 'Limit local account use of blank passwords to console logon only' is not enabled."
}

This is the second setting to enable insecure guest login
# In a similar manner enable insecure guest login
$LanmanPath = "HKLM:Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\LanmanWorkstation"
$LanmanName = "AllowInsecureGuestAuth"
$LanmanValue = 1
if (!(Test-Path -Path $LanmanPath\$LanmanName)) {
    New-ItemProperty -Path $LanmanPath -Name $LanmanName -PropertyType DWord -Value $LanmanValue
} else {
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $LanmanPath -Name $LanmanName -Value $LanmanValue
}

First script for policy changes work well. But second script to enable insecure login fails. I get following error
New-ItemProperty : Cannot find path 
'HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\LanmanWorkstation' because it does not exist.   
At line:1 char:1
+ New-ItemProperty -Path $LanmanPath -Name $LanmanName -PropertyType DW ...
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemPropertyC  
   ommand

As I said, I am neither an windows expert nor an poweshell expert. I am able to do the above manually using control panel and gpedit. But I am not able to do this using powershell script. ANy pointers are welcome.
